# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy: Blocks all egress though no blocks are specified

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy, egress

I have a service that I want to be able to access the internet and noother pods. However, ALL egress rules seem to block all egress.

```
# No NetworkPolicies
kubectl -n mytestnamespace exec service-c-78f784b475-qsdqg -- bin/bash -c 'curl www.google.com'
```

With no NetworkPolicy my pod can access the internet. Next I make a Networkpolicy that allows egress to all IP-addresses.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all
  namespace: mytestnamespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

But now curl can no longer access the internet, but WHY??????

## With NetworkPolicies allowing Egress to all IPs!

```
kubectl -n mytestnamespace exec service-c-78f784b475-qsdqg -- bin/bash -c 'curl www.google.com'
```

Why does this NetworkPolicy block all egress? Makes no sense!

Comment: using microk8s on Ubuntu 20.04 I am unable to reproduce what you show.  Good question for clarity btw, nice

Comment: @Vorsprung so if you use the same policy, your egress is still working?

Comment: yes, if I use the cidr:0.0.0.0/0 policy it does work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that despite opening up to all IP-addresses, the networkpolicy does not allow egress to the DNS pod, which is in another namespace.

```
# Identifying DNS pod
kubectl get pods -A | grep dns

# Identifying DNS pod label
kubectl describe pods -n kube-system coredns-64cfd66f7-rzgwk
```

Next I add the dns label to the egress policy:

```
# network_policy.yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-all
  namespace: mytestnamespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: "0.0.0.0/0"
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: "kube-system"
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: "kube-dns"
```

I apply the network policy and test the curl calls:

```
# Setting up policy
kubectl apply -f network_policy.yaml

# Testing curl call
kubectl -n mytestnamespace exec service-c-78f784b475-qsdqg -- bin/bash -c 'curl www.google.com'
```

SUCCESS! Now I can make egress calls, next I just have to block the appropriate IP-addresses in the private network.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, `curl` attempts to form a 2-way TCP connection with the HTTP server at `www.google.com`. This means, *both* egress and ingress traffic need to be allowed on your policy. Currently, only out-bound traffic is allowed. Maybe, you'll be able to see this in more detail if you ran curl in verbose mode:

```
kubectl -n mytestnamespace exec service-c-78f784b475-qsdqg -- bin/bash -c 'curl www.google.com' -v
```

You can then see the communication back and forth marked by arrows `>` (out-going) and `<` (in-coming). You'll notice only `>` arrows will be listed and no `<` traffic will be shown.

> Note: If you do something simpler like `ping google.com` it might work, since this is a simple state-less communication.

In order to have this, you can simply add an allow-all ingress rule to your policy like:

```
ingress:
  - {}
```

Also, there's a simpler way to allow all egress traffic simply as:

```
egress:
  - {}
```

I hope this helps. You can read more about policies [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).

Comment: Are you sure about this? If I make a policy that blocks all ingress, I can still connect to the internet using curl. I have also tried using "ping", and the egress-policy also blocks ping. Adding the two rules that you suggest, would be equal not to having a NetworkPolicy as ingress/egress is open by default.

Comment: This is incorrect. Quoting from the page linked to in the answer:

"When a pod is isolated for egress, the only allowed connections from the pod are those allowed by the egress list of some NetworkPolicy that applies to the pod for egress. Reply traffic for those allowed connections will also be implicitly allowed."